# Copy image from URL, change name and save to folder

Tags: php

Im about to start on a PHP script to import csv database.

The csv has a column with urls to product images.

What I need to be able to do is get the image, check what type of file it is (jpg, png etc), change the name, save the file to a folder on the server and then insert the file name into the database.

The inserting into the database bit I can do, its the renaming of the file im confused with.

Is it possible to grab the info like you would when uploading a file, for example:

Uploading a file using a file input in a html form

```
$_FILES['file']['name'];
or
$_FILES['file']['type'];
```

If downloading a file, could this be possible

```
$downloaded_image['name'];
or
$downloaded_image['type'];
```

or is that totally off the mark?

I have never done this before, and most of the answers on stackoverflow don't quite answer my question so was hoping someone could point me in the right direction on how to do this.

EDITED/UPDATED:

Would something like this work to get the file attributes...

```
$image_id = '123456';
$the_image = file_get_contents($downloaded_image);
$image_name = $the_image['name'];
$image_type = $the_image['type'];

$new_name = $image_id . '.' . $image_type;

$img_path = '/images/';
$save_image = file_put_contents($img_path, $new_name);
if($save_image) {
echo 'image saved';
} else {
echo 'Not Saved';
}
```

Hopefully im making some sense.

UPDATE: here is the script as it is (still needs tidying up)

```
define('CSV_PATH','E:/xampp/htdocs/aff/csv-import/');
// path where your CSV file is located

$csv_file = CSV_PATH . "infotuts.csv"; // Name of your CSV file
$csvfile = fopen($csv_file, 'r');
$theData = fgets($csvfile);
$i = 0;
while (!feof($csvfile)) {
    $csv_data[] = fgets($csvfile, 1024);
    $csv_array = explode(",", $csv_data[$i]);
    $insert_csv = array();
    $insert_csv['test_id'] = $csv_array[0];
    // $insert_csv['test_aw_id'] = $csv_array[1];
    // $insert_csv['test_name'] = $csv_array[2];
    $image_id = $csv_array[1];
    $download_image = $csv_array[2];

    // Store the original filename
    $original_name = basename($download_image);

    // Original extension by string manipulation
    $original_extension = substr($original_name, strrpos($original_name, '.')); // ".jpg"

    // An array to match mime types from finfo_file() with extensions
    // Use of finfo_file() is recommended if you can't trust the input
    // filename's extension
    $types = array('image/jpeg' => '.jpg','image/png' => '.png','image/gif' => '.gif');

    // Get the file and save it
    $img = file_get_contents($download_image);
    $stored_name = 'images/' . $image_id . $original_extension;
    if ($img) {
      file_put_contents($stored_name);

      // Get the filesize if needed
      $size = filesize($stored_name);

      // If you don't care about validating the mime type, skip all of this...
      // Check the file information
      $finfo = finfo_open(FILEINFO_MIME_TYPE);
      $mimetype = finfo_file($finfo, $stored_name);

      // Lookup the type in your array to get the extension
      if (isset($types[$mimetype])) {
        // if the reported type doesn't match the original extension, rename the file
        if ($types[$mimetype] != $original_extension) {
          rename($stored_name, 'images/' . $image_id . $types[$mimetype]);
        }
      }
      else {
        // unknown type, handle accordingly...
      }
      finfo_close($finfo);

        $query = "INSERT INTO test(test_id, test_aw_id, test_name) VALUES ('', '$image_id', '$stored_name')";
        $n=mysqli_query($con, $query);
        $i++;
    }
    else {
      echo 'Could not get file';
    }

}
fclose($csvfile);
```

Comment: It depends what is php configuration about open urls. If it is permited, then you can use $fileContents = file_get_contents(image_url_there); The type you can get from the file extension. Else you should use curl to get external content

Comment: No. file_get_contents gets the file content. The filename is in the url you open. The filetype you can get from the file extension or use fileinfo function.

Comment: In your proposed code, where does `$download_image` come from? Is this an image on your filesystem you are supplying for download by your users, or is this an image you are retrieving (downloading) from another location and saving it? I think I misunderstood your intent earlier.

Comment: _"The csv has a column with urls to product images"_ I get it now. You're retrieving the images, gathering info, and saving them.

Comment: Do the URL values of `$downloaded_image` include a full filename like `http://example.com/images/img1.jpg` or are they not image-like URLs: `http://example.com/images/?id=12345`?

Comment: Probably my fault, it gone 2am and im tired so probably not explaining myself very well, but yes, the csv has a column with urls to product images.

Comment: full filename - http://example.com/images/image1.jpg (or png)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By retrieving the file with `file_get_contents()`, you won't get any particularly useful information about its format. It carries no metadata similar to that found in `$_FILES` for upload.

If the image URLs are expected to be a full filename with an extension, and you *trust* the extension to be correct, you may use that as your type.  However, [`finfo_file()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.finfo-file.php) with the `FILEINFO_MIME_TYPE` option will probe the file to return its mime type, as in `image/jpeg` or `image/png`.

So your workflow will be to:

1. Retrieve the image with `file_get_contents()`
2. Save it to your local filesystem with its new name
3. Call `finfo_file()` to retrieve its mime type
4. Update your database with the desired details.

Example:

```
// Assume this URL for $download_image from your CSV
$download_image = 'http://example.com/images/img1.jpg';
$image_id = 12345;

// Store the original filename
$original_name = basename($download_image); // "img1.jpg"
// Original extension by string manipulation
$original_extension = substr($original_name, strrpos($original_name, '.')); // ".jpg"

// An array to match mime types from finfo_file() with extensions
// Use of finfo_file() is recommended if you can't trust the input
// filename's extension
$types = array(
  'image/jpeg' => '.jpg',
  'image/png' => '.png',
  'image/gif' => '.gif'
  // Other types as needed...
);

// Get the file and save it
$img = file_get_contents($download_image);
$stored_name = 'images/' . $image_id . $original_extension;
if ($img) {
  file_put_contents($stored_name, $img);

  // Get the filesize if needed
  $size = filesize($stored_name);

  // If you don't care about validating the mime type, skip all of this...
  // Check the file information
  $finfo = finfo_open(FILEINFO_MIME_TYPE);
  $mimetype = finfo_file($finfo, $stored_name);

  // Lookup the type in your array to get the extension
  if (isset($types[$mimetype])) {
    // if the reported type doesn't match the original extension, rename the file
    if ($types[$mimetype] != $original_extension) {
      rename($stored_name, 'images/' . $image_id . $types[$mimetype]);
    }
  }
  else {
    // unknown type, handle accordingly...
  }
  finfo_close($finfo);

  // Now save all the extra info you retrieved into your database however you normally would
  // $mimetype, $original_name, $original_extension, $filesize
}
else {
  // Error, couldn't get file
}
```

If you want to get the mimetype string from the extension you already have, and aren't validating the type with finfo, you can flip the `$types` to swap keys with values.

```
if (in_array($original_extension), $types) {
  $mimetype = array_flip($types)[$original_extension];
}
```

Comment: Yep, its just gone 3am and im about ready for my bed now for my 4 hours sleep before the kids drag me out of bed in the morning. lol...  Michael, you have gone above and beyond. I was just looking for pointers, but instead I got pretty much everything I need to get started on that portion of the script. Really do appreciate the help. Thanks a mil!

Comment: Hey @MichaelBerkowski, I tried what you had above, with a few changes to suite my test script.. I got the error: Warning: file_get_contents(http://www.partydomain.co.uk/images/P/21478.jpg ): failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.0 404 Not Found in E:\xampp\htdocs\aff\admin\import_products.php on line 34 - Line 34 is `$img = file_get_contents($download_image);`

Comment: Added teh test script code above in original question.

Comment: @EoinH That's a 404, which means the code works but the image can't be found. Now, I _am_ able to retrieve that image via `file_get_contents('http://www.partydomain.co.uk/images/P/21478.jpg')` so that raises suspicion about the server  -- have you scraped too many images from them such that they would block your IP and start returning 404s?

Comment: That was the first time I ran the script, and have not scrapped anything from them at all. They actually provide the info (via affiliate agent) so people can scrape the images.

Comment: @EoinH Something local is causing the 404. Boiled down to a very simple case, the image is accessible: http://codepad.viper-7.com/NtHXVR

Comment: @EoinH (by the way, I noticed I had been missing the second arg to `file_put_contents()` later in the script. I only had the filename there, and not the actual data to save in the file)

Comment: Right, so it looks like it was the server blocking me. I got a new list of images hosted on productserve.com which seems to be working fine. And I presume the missing arg shoudl be put in like so: `file_put_contents($stored_name, $image_id . '.' . $types);`

Comment: @EoinH I edited to correct it above, should be `file_put_contents($stored_name, $img);` (filename, data) and only needed if the type doesn't match the extension

Comment: A few tweaks and I have the test script working now. (Posted Code Below). I'm going to stick it on a live server and see how she goes. I had a small issue where all images were saving as .gif's, so made a change to the rename() function, now im getting the correct file extention. Thanks again for all your help so far. I woudl have been lost without you!

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php

include_once('includes/functions.php');

define('CSV_PATH','E:/xampp/htdocs/aff/csv-import/');

$csv_file = CSV_PATH . "infotuts.csv";
$csvfile = fopen($csv_file, 'r');
$theData = fgets($csvfile);
$i = 0;
while (!feof($csvfile)) {
    $csv_data[] = fgets($csvfile, 1024);
    $csv_array = explode(",", $csv_data[$i]);
    $insert_csv = array();
    $insert_csv['test_id'] = $csv_array[0];
    $insert_csv['test_aw_id'] = $csv_array[1];
    $insert_csv['test_name'] = $csv_array[2];

    $image_id = $insert_csv['test_aw_id'];
    $download_image = $insert_csv['test_name'];

    $original_name = basename($download_image);

    $original_extension = substr($original_name, strrpos($original_name, '.')); // ".jpg"

    $types = array('image/jpeg' => '.jpg','image/png' => '.png','image/gif' => '.gif');

    $img = file_get_contents($download_image);
    $stored_name = $image_id . $original_extension;
    $stored_name = trim($stored_name);
    if ($img) {
      file_put_contents($stored_name, $img);

      //$size = filesize($stored_name);

      $finfo = finfo_open(FILEINFO_MIME_TYPE);
      $mimetype = finfo_file($finfo, $stored_name);
      if (isset($types[$mimetype])) {
        if ($types[$mimetype] != $original_extension) {
          rename($stored_name, 'E:/xampp/htdocs/aff/images/products/' . $stored_name);

        }
      }
      else {

      }
      finfo_close($finfo);

        $query = "INSERT INTO test(test_id, test_aw_id, test_name) VALUES ('', '$image_id', '$stored_name')";
        $n=mysqli_query($con, $query);
        $i++;
    }
    else {
      echo 'Could not get file';
    }

}
fclose($csvfile);

echo "File data successfully imported to database!!";
mysqli_close($con);
?>
```