# php cannot save external image to file

Tags: php

For some reason I cannot get the google map image to save to a file.

Here is my code:

```
 $rs=mysqli_fetch_assoc(mysqli_query($dbh,"select latitude,longitude from locations where locid=$locid"));
 $lat=$rs[latitude];$lon=$rs[longitude];
 $mapUrl="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?center=$lat,$lon&zoom=13&size=400x280&key=".google_apikey;
 $tmp="/srv/www/data/maps/tmp.png";
 touch($tmp);chmod($tmp,0777);
 file_put_contents($tmp,file_get_contents($mapUrl));
```

The resulting image saved in `tmp.png is 0 bytes` **however when i go to the map url explicitly it shows**

Not quite sure whats wrong here.

Comment: 'blank'? as in you get a 400x280 all-black image? or the .png is 0-bytes? right now you're just ASSUMING that the file_get_contents and file_put_contents calls actually succeeded.

Comment: Don't nest functions when you're debugging. I'm guessing SSL failed on your server so file_get_contents returned nothing. Are you sure var_dump(file_get_contents($mapUrl)) is not empty?

Comment: 0 bytes means your f_g_c call failed, so you need to figure out why. maybe google's blacklisted your IP

Comment: @MarcB thanks i switched servers and it works now.

Comment: better start coding defensively. Never **EVER** assume that an operation with an external resource succeeded. Always assume failure, check for failure, and treat success as a pleasant surprise.

Comment: @MarcB Im waiting for you to post the answer so i can accept it.

Answer (score 0):

Go to the selected answer on this page: [Copy image from URL, change name and save to folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25655431/copy-image-from-url-change-name-and-save-to-folder)

Tweak it to your needs because it all works great. I was a having similar issues and some pieces of that stack solved my troubles, Be sure your dirs are 777 and you are SSL compliant. My issue turned out to be a midnight hour attention to detail. I'm so use to root '/images/my/path/here.extension' that I neglected to change it to 'images/...'. Doh! Sometimes it can be something so simple.